# How to generate snippets from existing code?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, code-snippets

I've got some pieces of code I need to turn in to snippets. Anyone know a good tool of visual studio plug-in that can do something like this?

Basically I would like to be able to parameterize code like this:

```
//MOVE TO TOP!!
private XmlData subject;

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the subject.
/// </summary>
/// <value>
/// The subject.
/// </value>
public XmlData Subject
{
    get
    {
        if (subject == null)
        {
            subject = CreateXmlDataInstance(Post_DA.SUBJECT_FIELD);
        }
        return subject;
    }
    set
    {
        subject = value;
    }
}
```

I hope one of you guys know a good tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create snippets manually, but maybe a snippet designer like this can help you:
[SnippetDesigner](http://snippetdesigner.codeplex.com/)

I don't think you could do that automatically any way - you have to define which elements to parameterize at least.